# using re in creating stopwords list

Tags: python, regex, customization, stop-words

I'd like to create my own stopword list. In order to tackle lower & upper case, I want to incorporate re in the list:

```
new_stopwords = ['food','eat','drink','order','time',r'[?M?m?c?C\S]','service']
```

`r'[?M?m?c?C\S]'` meant to find all the variation of McDonald's. but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What are the actual McDonald's-related terms which you want to match?

Comment: the actual document are 1000+ yelp reviews for McDonald's. here's one of them:                            
review=['Terrible customer service. I came in at 9:30pm and stood in front of the register and no one bothered to say anything or help me for 5 minutes. There was no one else waiting for their food inside either, just outside at the window.  I left and went to Chickfila next door and was greeted before I was all the way inside. This McDonalds is also dirty, the floor was covered with dropped food. Obviously filled with surly and unhappy workers.]

Answer (score 0):

You are making the common beginner mistake of assuming the square brackets do ... something which they don't do.  Square brackets in a regex introduce a *character class* where the regex engine will match any one of the characters between the square brackets.  So `[M?m?]` will match a single `M`, or a `?`, or an `m` (or a `?`, but we already said that, didn't we?)

Probably you are looking for something like

```
r"[Mm][Cc][Dd]\w+'?s"
```

which will match upper or lower case `M`, followed by upper or lower case `C`, followed by upper or lower case `D`, followed by any "word" character `\w`, repeated once or more times `+`, followed by an apostrophe `'` which is optional `?` followed by a lowercase `s`.

We can't read your mind, but hopefully this should at least help you  better articulate what you do want to say. The [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) outlines some common beginner mistakes and how to avoid them, and has pointers to more learning and testing resources related to regular expressions.